# How can I stop the outline bar in storyboard interface builder from automatically scrolling to top?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

After selecting a view as in the first screenshot below, either collapse a view or clicking somewhere else to lose its focus will make the bar automatically scroll to the top as in the second screenshot. Is this a bug of Xcode? If not, how can I get rid of this bad behaviour?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: also when I'm deleting some view, that piece of art scrolls the list as well